# Cannot open "" for writing -- sharin violation on path. External Harddrive

Tags: macos, xamarin.forms, visual-studio-mac

I just got a new external SSD and since my macbook has only 128gb capacity, I thought that I could create my Xamarin projects on SSD. It is formatted exFAT and I tried to build project on windows and it is working properly.

When building on the visual studio for mac it gives CS2012 error. I checked the permissions on external disk and it is not read only.

"Cannot open '/Volumes/SSD/Project/obj/Debug/netstandart2.0/app.pdb' for writing -- Sharing violation on path '/Volumes/SSD/Project/obj/Debug/netstandart2.0/app.pdb' (CS2012)

Comment: This is not a xamarin problem , you can move to [Developer Community](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/report?space=41&entry=problem) to report a problem  for better support .

Answer (score 0):

Mono does not currently support drives that use the FAT file system.

https://github.com/mono/mono/issues/19221

The only workaround is to format your drive using some other file system format.